# In code igniter multiple image update

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i do multiple image upload in code igniter the same code is used to update the the multiple image but in the update time i change name  i don't change images then click ok button  the name is update but the images are missing but i change the image the that only update..why?

my controller

```html
 function update_products() 
     { 
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $dataInfo = array();
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload();
       
           $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();

    }
   $data = array(
        
         'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
         'prod_image' => $dataInfo[0]['file_name'],
          'prod_image1' => $dataInfo[1]['file_name'],
          'prod_image2' => $dataInfo[2]['file_name'],
         'upadted_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')  
      );
   
    $stock = array(
     'discount' => $this->input->post('discount'),
    );
                 $this->db->where('prod_id', $id);
                $this->db->update('tbl_products', $data);
             $this->db->where('prods_id', $id);
             $this->db->update('otc_product_discount', $stock);
        
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully updated!</div>');
      redirect('index.php/admin/display_product_list');
                 
  }         
    }
```

my view

```html
 <label for="type">Product Image</label>
<img src="<?php echo base_url("./resources/images/products/");  if($row->prod_image) echo $row->prod_image; else echo "no-img.jpg"; ?>" alt="" height="50" width="50"/>
<input type="file" id="med_img" class="file_upload"  name="userfile[]" value="<?php  echo $row->prod_image; ?>" /> 

<label for="type">Product Image2</label>
<img src="<?php echo base_url("./resources/images/products/");  if($row->prod_image1) echo $row->prod_image1; else echo "no-img.jpg"; ?>" alt="" height="50" width="50"/>
<input type="file" id="med_img" class="file_upload"  name="userfile[]" value="<?php  echo $row->prod_image1; ?>" />
<label for="type">Product Image3</label>
<img src="<?php echo base_url("./resources/images/products/");  if($row->prod_image2) echo $row->prod_image2; else echo "no-img.jpg"; ?>" alt="" height="50" width="50"/>
                  <input type="file" id="med_img" class="file_upload"  name="userfile[]" value="<?php  echo $row->prod_image2; ?>" />
```

uplaod function is

```html
private function set_upload_options()
{   
    //upload an image options
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './resources/images/products/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']      = '0';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

    return $config;
}
```

Comment: `name` and `upadted_time` field properly updated. right?

Comment: yes. the image missing  i don't change the image

Comment: any help? @ Razib Al Mamun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks need to upload individually like that in your controller.

```
function update_products() 
{ 
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());

    $data = array();

    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {   
        $dataInfo = $this->upload->data();
        $data['prod_image'] = $dataInfo['file_name'];
    }

    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile1')) {   
        $dataInfo = $this->upload->data();
        $data['prod_image1'] = $dataInfo['file_name'];
    }

    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile2')) {   
        $dataInfo = $this->upload->data();
        $data['prod_image2'] = $dataInfo['file_name'];
    }   

    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name'),
    $data['upadted_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')  

    $stock = array(
    'discount' => $this->input->post('discount'),
    );

    $this->db->where('prod_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_products', $data);

    $this->db->where('prods_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('otc_product_discount', $stock);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully updated!</div>');
    redirect('index.php/admin/display_product_list');
}
```

Change `FIlE` input field name `userfile` `userfile1` and `userfile2` like bellow :

```
<input type="file" id="med_img" class="file_upload"  name="userfile"/>
<input type="file" id="med_img" class="file_upload"  name="userfile1"/>
<input type="file" id="med_img" class="file_upload"  name="userfile2"/>
```

Comment: the view part is change to like this

Comment: in view part some change just input field

Comment: what is situation now?

Comment: now the image don't update but not any change and we click ok button image still here..

Comment: upload 1 or 3 images then see

Comment: i have edited my answer. please replace this method code `update_products()`

Comment: for details : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller

Comment: how you can checked please descript me step by step

Comment: i thinks it will work all 3 images, please check carefully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129011/discussion-between-razib-al-mamun-and-antroo-ghosh).